# Converting image to bas64string in react.native.android SDK using pdfbox

Tags: android, react-native, pdfbox

I am trying to extract text from a pdf and want to also include images.

Those images I am getting from `pdfbox` page object.

Now what I have in mind is using base64converter.

After searching the net I found that I could use The below code to do it

```java
    public static String imgToBase64String(final BufferedImage img, final String formatName) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, formatName, os);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os.toByteArray());
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

The problem With the below code is that in `react-native.android` dose not include `BufferedImage`  , `ImageIO` or `Base64` in its SDK

How am I going to do this? Are there any alternative way in doing this?

Here is the complete code below incase

```java
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.viliussutkus89.android.pdf2htmlex.pdf2htmlEX;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; // Import this class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files

import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.PDXObject;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.COSName;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardProtectionPolicy;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactory;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.LosslessFactory;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDCheckBox;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDComboBox;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDListBox;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDRadioButton;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.android.PDFBoxResourceLoader;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

// below Import are not found in the SDK
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;

public class PdfToHtmlModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    // add to CalendarModule.java
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "PdfToHtmlModule";
    }

    private ReactApplicationContext appContext;

    PdfToHtmlModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        appContext = context;
        PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(appContext.getApplicationContext());
    }
    public static String imgToBase64String(final BufferedImage img, final String formatName) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, formatName, os);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os.toByteArray());
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void getCompleteTextFromPdf(String pdfFilePath, Promise promise) {
        try {
            String pdfText = "";
            File file = new File(pdfFilePath);
            WritableMap params = this.getPDFInfo(file);
            WritableArray array = new WritableNativeArray();
            PDDocument pddoc = PDDocument.load(file);
            if (pddoc.isEncrypted()) {
                pddoc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < pddoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                PDFTextStripper pdfstripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                pdfstripper.setStartPage(i);
                pdfstripper.setEndPage(i);
                pdfText = pdfstripper.getText(pddoc);
                PDPage page = pddoc.getPage(i);
                PDResources rs = page.getResources();
                for (COSName cosObj : rs.getXObjectNames()) {
                    PDXObject obj = rs.getXObject(cosObj);
                    if (obj instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                        // this doe not work yet
                        String base64String = PdfToHtmlModule.imgToBase64String(((PDImageXObject) obj).getImage(), "png");
                        if (base64String != "")
                            array.pushString("data:image/png;" + base64String);
                    }
                }
                array.pushString(pdfText);
            }
            pddoc.close();
            params.putArray("chapters", array);
            promise.resolve(params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            promise.reject(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: We use this library for base64 encoding/ decoding
https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64

Comment: and we use [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) for file I/O

Comment: I need this on android. Course I am extracting the image from pdf and have somehow to pass it